# What is the cleanest way to temporarily disable a keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, accessibility

I have a strange problem, and it involves my keyboard and a cat.

I have a computer in a shared office, and this is my machine. But there’s also a cat in the office, that likes to walk on keyboards. So every day when I come back to log-in, I see this :

[image: Many Dots filled up !]

I know I can unplug the USB at night, but I am looking for a quicker way. Is there a  less-manual way? I’d like to disable the keyboard easily, and re-enable upon coming back to office

Comment: Put a cardboard box over the keyboard when you leave.

Comment: Wow, a cat that knows how to press CTRL+ALT+CANC?